# Is it possible that fusion logs won't capture some assembly loads?

Tags: c#, .net

My app is failing with `MissingMethodException` because apparently an old version of the assembly gets loaded.

- I enabled fusion logs to see where it gets loaded from. I see 4 load requests and all of them say they are loading assembly from a path that has the latest version of the assembly.
- I also verified that the assembly is not in GAC.

**Could it be possible that an assembly load is not getting captured in fusion logs?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very unlikely that fusion log says otherwise. Since fusion log is not helping, you can check where and all the assembly gets loaded from using procmon.

1. Start procmon.
2. Reproduce the issue.
3. Stop procmon.
4. In the procmon trace, go to filter and filter for your exe first.
5. Then add filter for path contains your DLL name.

This will give you all the probed path and loaded from path. Since you got missing method exception, it will also be good idea to check if the method actually exists in the so called DLL using ILSpy.